# Using 3 equations, find $2a-b+c$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

From the problem, I extract the following 3 equations.

1. $a+b+c=10$
2. $ab+bc+ca=31$
3. $abc=30$

The question is to find $(2a-b+c)$.

---

Using the equation $(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 +2 (ab+bc+ca)$, I found $a^2+b^2+c^2=38$.

Using the equation $a^3+b^3+c^3 - 3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2 + b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$, I found $a^3+b^3+c^3=160$.

However, I was stuck here. Please let me know some directions. Thank you.

Comment: The numbers are 2, 3 and 5. Without a given criterion for assigning them to $a$, $b$ and $c$, you can't find $2a-b+c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Viete $a$, $b$ and $c$ are roots of the following equation:
$$x^3-10x^2+31x-30=0$$ or
$$(x-2)(x-5)(x-3)=0$$
and the rest for you.

Comment: Wow... This is what I never can recall, but very wonderful solving... If I met another problem like this, maybe... I will solve the problem like Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's answer.... Surely, this solving is very nice.... but my creativity is....... :(

Answer (score 1):

the first equation gives:
$$a+b=10-c$$
the second one:
$$c(a+b)=31-ab$$ with the first
$$c(10-c)=31-ab$$ and with $$c=\frac{30}{ab}$$ we obtain
$$c(10-c)=31-\frac{30}{c}$$
can you proceed?

Comment: Oh my god!!! This proceed is very impressed!!!! Multiplying by $c$, I can find $c$ using the "Synthetic division". Thank you so much!!